# What is it called when you have multiple data structures, but not connected with json in jq?

Tags: jq

For instance, I might have something coming out of my `jq` command like this:

```
"some string"
"some thing"
"some ping"
...
```

Note that there is no outer object or array and no commas between items.

Or you might have something like:

```
["some string"
"some thing"
"some ping"]
["some wing"
"some bling"
"some fing"]
```

But again, no commas or outer object or array and no commas between them to indicate that this is JSON.

I keep thinking the answer is that it is called "raw", but I'm uncertain about this.

I'm specifically looking for a term to look for in the documentation that allows you to process the sorts of examples above, and I am at a loss as how to proceed.

Comment: `jq` normally won't produce output like your second example unless you really go out of your way with string formatting.  Are you sure there aren't supposed to be commas separating the strings inside the arrays?

Comment: The first one is simply a stream of separate JSON values, which `jq` handle without any special treatment; it simply loops over them separately. The second one is just plain text. There's isn't much you can do with it besides use `jq -r` and process the input line-by-line.

Comment: @chepner - I think you meant `jq -R`.  @leeand00 - Your second example could be described as 'invalid JSON'.  There are command-line tools (such as any-json and hjson) which can be helpful in converting invalid JSON to JSON, but none that I know of handles your examples of invalid arrays.

Comment: I believe you can also just put brackets around it `[ <your-big-long-expression-here> ]` and the list / stream will become an array.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, the [jq manual.yml](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/docs/content/3.manual/manual.yml#L20-L32) describes the behavior of filters this way:

> Some filters produce multiple results, for instance there's one that
>     produces all the elements of its input array. Piping that filter
>     into a second runs the second filter for each element of the
>     array. Generally, things that would be done with loops and iteration
>     in other languages are just done by gluing filters together in jq.
>
> It's important to remember that every filter has an input and an
>     output. Even literals like "hello" or 42 are filters - they take an
>     input but always produce the same literal as output. Operations that
>     combine two filters, like addition, generally feed the same input to
>     both and combine the results. So, you can implement an averaging
>     filter as `add / length` - feeding the input array both to the `add`
>     filter and the `length` filter and then performing the division.

It's also important to keep in mind that the default behavior of jq is to run the filter you specify once for each JSON object.  In the following example, jq runs the identity filter four times passing one value to it each time:

```
$ (echo 2;echo {}; echo []; echo 3) | jq .
2
{}
[]
3
```

What is happening here is similar to

```
$ jq -n '2, {}, [], 3 | .'
2
{}
[]
3
```

Since this isn't always what you want, the `-s` option can be used to tell jq to gather the separate values into an array and feed that to the filter:

```
$ (echo 2;echo {}; echo []; echo 3)| jq -s .
[
  2,
  {},
  [],
  3
]
```

which is similar to

```
$ jq -n '[2, {}, [], 3] | .'
[
  2,
  {},
  [],
  3
]
```

The [jq manual.yml](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/docs/content/3.manual/manual.yml#L130-L135) explains how the `--raw-input`/`-R` option can be included for even more control over input handing:

> Don't parse the input as JSON. Instead, each line of text is passed to the filter as a string. If combined with `--slurp`,then the entire input is passed to the filter as a single long string.

You can see using the `-s` and `-R` options together in this example produces a different result:

```
$ (echo 2;echo {}; echo []; echo 3)| jq -s -R .
"2\n{}\n[]\n3\n"
```